# Which one is better to use to dispose an object?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, memory-leaks, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing an app windows phone 8 and i was wondering making **null** is a good way to dispose an **object** from **memory** or should i do something different or extra to **dispose** an object...!

Moreover, I have a class name 'A' and this 'A class contains **observable collections** and other kind of objects. Therefore, when I feel i don't need to use the class anymore, for example leaving the page, I make that class 'A' object null. Is it a good practice to do or should I do something different?

Comment: Is `A` `IDisposable`? If not, I  wouldn't worry, as soon as it is out of scope `GC` handles it.

Comment: You can use _using statement_.

Comment: I did not create a idisposable methods, should i create one then?
@Yuriy would you be kind of enough to explain your answer bit more? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't sound like there is anything to dispose

Comment: However, there are object arrays in that class, doesn't that matter?

Answer (score 0):

if your code is managed then just null the object, CLR will manage rest of the things. If your code is un-managed then implement **IDsposable** interface and call Dispose method.